# Swagger-ui does not hide readOnly nested object from example body

Tags: java, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm developing spring-boot app with swagger-ui and lombok. Currently I'm trying to hide nested object from request body, but it still shows in example json on swagger-ui page.

I have my class with annotations(simplified to only related stuff):

```
@Data
@ApiModel(description = "Character model")
public class Character {

    @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
    private Long id;

    @ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
    private SearchAnnouncement searchAnnouncement;
}
```

Note: @Data is Lombok annotation that generates getters, setters and few other things

When I access example model on swagger page "id" filed is properly hidden in example json, and visible in response model.
But "searchAnnouncement" is not hidden in example json.

I tried:

- using readOnly = true
- using accessMode = ApiModelProperty.AccessMode.READ_ONLY
- using @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE), which prevents generation of setter for that field, as I read somewhere that something is checking if setter exist and sets readOnly based on that
- different combinations of above

but in all cases example json looks like this (id hidden, and searchAnnouncement visible):

```
{
    "searchAnnouncement": {
         "id": 0,
    },
}
```

So in short my question is:

## Is it possible to hide from example json nested object?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention I currently have swagger2 & swagger-ui with version 2.9.2 in my dependencies, but I moved up from 2.8.0 hoping to hide this nested object

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by setting `jsonIgnore` on my setters. I'm using dependency version 2.9.2.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when reading the related data, the nested object is also ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Using `swagger3`:

```
@JsonReadOnly
@Schema(description = "ID", accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
private Long id;
```

Comment: I can't find `@JsonReadOnly`, but `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` works for me.