# Springfox Swagger-UI - hide or filter fields for different requests not using additional models

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is that possible to filter (hide) specific fields for different requests using Spring Boot and Springfox Swagger 2.9.2?

I got model "Genres":

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "type": "string"
}
```

And another one "Book" with the first included:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "isbn": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "author": "string",
  "publishedYear": "string",
  "price": "string",
  "quantity": 0
}
```

I want to show all fields for the first model "Genres" in Swagger-UI `GET /genres`
but hide `"type": "string"` for "Book" model `POST /books` since it's not mandatory and basically duplicate info about book genre.

Is there any possibility to do that? I don't want to use DTO or any separate models to do this, but to my astonishment, it's seems there is no other choice since Swagger developers didn't leave such a possibility.

I tried:

```
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
private String type;
```

And:

```
@ApiModelProperty(accessMode = ApiModelProperty.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
private String type;
```

But it didn't help.

@JsonIgnore hides field for every request which is not what I'm looking for:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String type;
```

I viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595540/springfox-hide-certain-fields-in-swagger-ui-that-arent-required-for-the-call#) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454357/swagger-ui-does-not-hide-readonly-nested-object-from-example-body), but it seems like there is no solution.
Do I miss something? Googling this issue I found a lot of people who look for this feature for years :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but using SpringFox 3 I've got this to work by annotating my field `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)`.